# Proximity Sensor state not enable in ios7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
UIDevice * device=[UIDevice currentDevice];
    device.proximityMonitoringEnabled=YES;

    state=device.proximityState;


    NSLog(@"%hhd",state);

    if(state)
    {

        NSLog(@"Proximity Sensor Starts YES");


        NSLog(@"%d",count);
        count++;
        NSLog(@"%d",count);


        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(aTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(proximityChanged:)
                                                     name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification"
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }

}
```

I have used this code to enable the proximity sensor state but every time my pointer goes to else condition why my proximity sensor not detected in ios7. tested on iPhone 5s.

why this happening please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `proximityMonitoringEnabled` flag again? Note what Apple says:

> Not all iOS devices have proximity sensors. To determine if proximity monitoring is available, attempt to enable it. If the value of the proximityMonitoringEnabled property remains NO, proximity monitoring is not available.

Edit.

`device.proximityState` doesn't say if your sensors are enabled. It is indicating whether the proximity sensor is close to the user or not in particular moment. You should register for notification and run timer not after `proximityState` check, but `proximityMonitoringEnabled`.

Comment: ya i check that enable this device.proximityMonitoringEnabled=YES;